# How Can I import excel file to multivalue field By feeds module?

Tags: 7, feeds

I use feeds_tamper and feeds module. I must import a xls file to drupal users by feeds module.

In my excel file every multivalue field data is as row.

I want to import separated Repetitious rows as multivalue field data.
Please see the picture:

[image]

I want to import Repetitious cells for a unique uid to multuvalue field.for example if uid is 14 , I have 2 rows for this user , I want to import every column as a value for multivalue field .

I can not change excel file because thats records is very huge.I have about 2000 rows in this  excel  file.

Comment: Pair of question:  Will be  this file changing frequently?, Can you have as limit a pair of rows for each uid, or could be N rows per uid?

Comment: No,I have not specified limit for rows that are Repetitious.Can be 2 rows or Can be 20 rows . If is necessary My limit of rows is 20.